# Automating Requests Through Postman

Tags: csv, automation, request, postman

I have ~10,000 records in a csv file that I need to run through postman and check the output it gives.

I was wondering (because I've been doing this manually) if there's a way to import the csv file into postman, and use the rows like variables and just 'scroll' through each result it gives out.

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature exists in Postman runner.

You have to make sure your CSV column's name(s) match the name(s) of your variable(s) in your collection.

You select your CSV file in the "data" part, just above the "start run", and when you run your collection, it will parse your file and replace the variable(s) with the value in the corresponding column and execute the request.
Then it will loop and get the next value and execute, and so on.

It just depends on the content of your CSV  file and how you use it in your Postman request.

You shall have a look at those links :

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files

[http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/)/

They will give you complete explanation about how it works.

Alex